# Need help Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My task is to uncheck the **checkbox** and again **check** the **checkbox**.

This is the website (Mentioned in code all the **selenium** script where to traverse).

I'm working on **selenium** **web driver** as a beginner, Well I got stuck at one place while running my selenium test script, I want to **unchecked** the **checkbox** which is at the bottom which says **agreed to the Terms and Conditions governing the use of Naukri.com**

I have reviewed the default Mailer & Communications settings.

Help would be very appreciated.

Error stack trace is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  
  Element is not clickable at the point. Other element would receive the
  click: <label for="term" class="customChkBoxLbl chkboxLbl"></label>
```

Code I have tried so far :

```
WebDriver driver13=new FirefoxDriver();
driver13.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver13.get("https://www.naukri.com/");
driver13.manage().window().maximize();
driver13.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"p0widget\"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")).click();
driver13.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='exp']")).click();
```

I tried with this also but getting the exception as:

below code is not working in spite I've written correct XPath:

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver13);
a.moveToElement(driver13.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='term']"))).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: It runs very fine. I am not getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking on "I am a Professional" you can use this code :

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20); 
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://my.naukri.com/account/createaccount");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@name='userType' and contains(text(),'Professional')]"))).click();

WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.id("term"));

System.out.println(checkBox.isSelected());   // this should print True (Because it is checked)


JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;  

Thread.sleep(2000); // for visualization purpose , you can remove it after the execution  

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkBox);  // Click it and Uncheck it.

System.out.println(checkBox.isSelected());  // this should print False (Because it is unchecked now)  

Thread.sleep(2000);  //for visualization purpose , you can remove it after the execution  

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkBox); //check it again

System.out.println(checkBox.isSelected());   // this should print True (Because it is checked)
```

Comment: Hi I am confused. I excuted the code he has given and I am receiving any such error. Do you receive that error?

Comment: @Rajagopalan : I did not run his code , let me run it and I will get back to you.

Comment: @Rajagopalan : I'm getting this error : `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='term']"}` , I do not why 3 windows got popped up including the main window when I ran his code.

Comment: Okay thank you , I missed out his second part of the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script my friend, it worked perfectly fine for me :) :)

Comment: what is java executor & why did you use javascript executor? Can you please explain me in detail as I'm beginner and I should be answerable to the one who assigned me task and got helped via you.

Comment: @Jahangirali Selenium was designed to interact with the page as a user would, e.g. if an element is not visible, Selenium will throw an error, etc. if you try to interact with it. Javascript Executor is a way to run Javascript on the page through Selenium. In this case, JS is being used to "cheat" and click the element you want. You need to be very careful with it's use. If you are trying to simulate a user's actions and experience, you should (in general) not use Javascript.

Comment: @Jahangirali : `JavascriptExecutor` is an interface in selenium. The main use of this is to execute JS through selenium. Sometimes `selenium web driver script was executed before the javascript onload event was triggered (Or finished executing). So the button.click would occur on a disabled element. And nothing would happen.`

Comment: @Jahangirali : Glad it worked for you. It is good to accept answer , if it is helpful. You can go through [https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer] , You will have to click on check mark which is just under the downvote button and besides the helpful answer. Thank you !

Comment: The link which you which you provided above,it says page not found.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is argument[0] and why we used?    **executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkBox); **              //Please explain this line anybody

Comment: checkBox  is a web element right , we are passing webelement (CheckBox) as `argument[0] ` in Java script call like this `executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", checkBox);`  see the return type of `WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.id("term"));`